# Cant get environmental key to read in my nodejs program

Tags: node.js, api, environment-variables

I have declared a environmental variable in which my console can read. I am now trying to get the environmental variable to read my script.js file so my API key stays secure but it wont read. How can i fix this?

The process.env works for a console call in my server.js file but not in this one. Please help me

```
// Create a request variable and assign a new XMLHttpRequest object to it.
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();


// Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint

request.open('GET', 'https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/testname?api_key=' + process.env.API_KEY, true);


request.onload = function () {


// Begin accessing JSON data here
}


// Send request
request.send();
```

Comment: How are you setting the env variable?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are actually setting the environment variable in the same shell context of the server application. You can't set the environment variable as a part of your bash_profile, and expect your server.js setup as an init process to read it. 
If you are just testing server.js on your shell, make sure you are setting the variable in the same shell, and then restarting the server.js process.

To print the list of variables, you can try `console.log(process.env)` to print the list of all variables, and use the `env` command in the shell to print all current variables.

If nothing else, setting the variable in the same statement and running your script should make it available in your script:

`API_KEY=abc node server.js`